# angularjs test a directive in a component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using angular js 1.5. I have a component which has a list of movies (array), and expects to render list of movies using a directive (movie-item).

I am trying to unit test this component and make sure it has already rendered movies that matched the movies list array length.

The movie-item directive expects to collect input from user, but i am just simplifying it.

How can I test that?

**Movie List Component**

```
   (function() {
    "use strict";

    var module = angular.module("psMovies");

    function controller() {
        var model = this;
        model.movies = [];

        model.$onInit = function() {
            model.movies = [{"id": 1,"title": "Star Wars"},{"id": 2,"title": "Star Trek"}];           
        };
    }

    module.component("movieList", {
        templateUrl: "movie-list.component.html",
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: [ controller]
    });

} ());
```

**movie-list.component html**

```
  <div ng-repeat="movie in model.movies">
        <movie-item item="movie"> </movie-item>
    </div>
```

**movie item component**

```js
angular.module('psMovies')
    .directive('movieItem', function() {
        "use strict";
        return {
            templateUrl: 'movie-item.component.html',
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                item: '=', 
            },
            link: function(scope) {

            }
        };
    });
```

**movie-item html**

```
 <div> {{model.id}}  - {{model.title}}</div>
```

**my unit test**

```
describe("The movieList component", function () {

    beforeEach(module("psMovies"));

    var moviesList;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($componentController) {
        moviesList = $componentController("movieList",{
           $scope: {} 
        });
    }));

    it("can be created", function () {
        expect(moviesList).toBeDefined();
        expect(moviesList.$onInit).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

Comment: The question isn't clear enough. Which one is a 'directive' and which one is a 'component'. There's only `movieItem` *component* in the code you've posted.

Comment: @estus, I fixed the question.

Comment: try to inject `beforeEach(inject(function ($componentController, _$rootScope_)` and assign it to `$scope = _$rootScope.new()_;`

Answer (score 0):

In order to test component/directive template, it should be compiled with `$compile`.

There's more than one way to test this. If nested directives/components are too complex, it makes sense to replace them with dummy directives/components for isolated testing, i.e. in `movieList` test `movieItem` can be mocked, just to test that it is bound properly in `movieList` template, something like:

```
describe('movieList tests', () => {
  beforeEach(module('psMovies', ($provide) => {
    $provide.directive('movieItem', () => ({
      scope: { item: '=' }
    }));
  });
  ...
  it('should compile movie items', inject(($rootScope) => {
    let scope = $rootScope.$new();
    const movieList = $compile('<movie-list>')(scope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    const mockedMovieItems = movieList.find('movie-item');
    expect(mockedMovieItems.length).toBe(2);
    const mockedMovieItem = mockedMovieItems[0];
    expect(mockedMovieItem.isolateScope().item).toEqual({"id": 1,"title": "Star Wars"});
    ...
  }));
});
```

Real `movieItem` can then be tested separately:

```
describe('movieItem tests', () => {
  beforeEach(module('psMovies'));
  ...
  it('should compile movie items', inject(($rootScope) => {
    let scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.movie = {"id": 1,"title": "Star Wars"};
    const movieItem = $compile('<movie-item item="movie">')(scope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(movieItem.isolateScope().item).toEqual({"id": 1,"title": "Star Wars"});
    ...
  }));
});
```